# Problems logging into chat using Tor

Tags: discussion, chat, login, tor

I'm trying to log into chat while using the Tor Browser. Attempting to log into [chat.stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/users/chat-login) brings you to https://chat.stackexchange.com/login/global-fallback, where you see the message `No referer was present - this may be due to a browser setting`.

What can I do about this? <sup><sub><sup>Or rather, what can the developers do about this? :)</sup></sub></sup>

Comment: The irony of this question is that Tor is designed to hide your identity. But if you login to a service, you've then exposed your identity. Since all this traffic is http, I'm thinking a malicious entity could determine who you are and then monitor you throughout the rest of your browser session. I'm no expert on this, but I was under the impression that you don't login to stuff while using Tor. If you [commit to the Tor proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/56447/tor?referrer=EZYxxM1sr4pW0VuASrAkNA2), maybe one of us can ask. :D) Hope this helps!

Comment: There is no irony here. :) When you login, you're pseudonymous, not anonymous. There is nothing wrong with that and no one can automagically find out who you really are. Long term pseudonyms have bigger risks. You can even use Tor and login with your real name, that won't give you anonymity, but location privacy which is worth something as well. One logged in, that still easily correlates with other tabs due to cookies, non-existent stream isolation and so forth. Use Tor Button's New Identity feature if you want to do different tasks.

Comment: I'm having this problem, too. I would assume that it's a Stack Exchange-side issue, given that I can log into SE itself and post to the Q&A parts just fine. Of course, I wouldn't have to use TOR at all if Stack Exchange would only support TLS everywhere, but [alas…](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Please report a bug: 
  https://trac.torproject.org/ 
  You can copy and paste what you wrote in your original question.
- Unless no one else can think of a clever workaround... There is not much you can do, other than reporting a bug and...
- Perhaps ask in #Tor @ irc.oftc.net as well.
- You could run iceweasel (that's how Firefox is named in Debian) in [Whonix-Workstation](https://www.whonix.org) and only use iceweasel for this very task. Could be overkill, though.
- Or try Liberte Linux, is has a non-TBB browser as well and might not have this bug.

(Full Disclosure: 
I am a maintainer of Whonix.)